# stringify rownames of big dataframe that match rows of a smaller dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Ok, is there a classy solution to the Question? Otherwise this is posted for future wanderers too.

This inelegant MWE essentially returns rownames of all identical rows matching over all columns. To do that, it collapses the rows into a smaller dataframe and then uses that dataframe to lookup the bigger dataframe.

More hacking can get me there. Like using regexes to remove the NA and manipulate strings. I am aware I will need to loop over identics.

Altogether, I gave up trying to find R libraries and functions that make this a straightforward task. Some functions only return the count of matches, others like `duplicated` truncate rows and columns. Verbs in `dplyr::.*` just discard row names.

```
ex<-data.frame(matrix(data=rep(0:1,25),nrow=5,ncol=5))
uniq<-unique(ex) #collapse to unique rows

identics<-matrix(NA) #dynamically hold identical names
identics<-as.data.frame(identics)

#sift ex using uniq and send matching rownames into identics
for(i in seq(nrow(uniq))){
  for(j in seq(nrow(ex))){
    if(identical(as.numeric(uniq[i,]),as.numeric(ex[j,]),num.eq = T)){
      print(paste(rownames(uniq[i,]),rownames(ex[j,]),sep = "=="))
      identics[i,j+1]<-rownames(ex[j,])
    }else{
      identics[i,j+1]<-NA
    }
  }
}
gsub("NA\\,|\\s+"," ",toString(identics[1,]))#remove NAs
```

Current output

```
  V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6
1 NA    1 <NA>    3 <NA>    5
2 NA <NA>    2 <NA>    4 <NA>
```

Desired

```
uniq: ex
1: 1, 3, 5
2: 2, 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible approach using `lapply` to loop over the rows of `uniq` and a join to filter for identical rows in `ex`:

```r
identics <- lapply(
  split(uniq, seq(nrow(uniq))),
  \(x) {
    ex |>
      transform(row = seq(nrow(ex))) |> 
      merge(x) |>
      subset(select = row, drop = TRUE) |> 
      paste(collapse = ", ")
  }
)

identics <- data.frame(
  uniq = names(identics),
  ex = unlist(identics)
)

identics
#>   uniq      ex
#> 1    1 1, 3, 5
#> 2    2    2, 4
```

Comment: Wonderful. Can you explain the thought process of the lapply function please. `\(x)` and `merge(x)`, are they referring to each other?

Comment: `\(x)` is short for `function(x)`. Using `lapply(split(uniq, seq(nrow(uniq))), ...` I first split uniq in a list of one-row data.frames. These are then passed to the function as `x`. Using `ex |> merge(x)` the I do an inner join of the one-row data.frames on ex just keeping only the rows where all columns match.